# Select a form from title when I open my app

Tags: powerapps

I'm making a budget app. When I choose new, I create a budget, with name like "BUXXX". Then, I can make a invest demand, with name like "DIXXX".
For this, I have two screens, and two forms, BudgetForm and DemandeForm. Of course, I use the first for a budget, and the second for a demande.

Then, I open a budget line in my sharepoint library, and it open with BudgetForm, and everything is good. But when I open a demande line... it use BudgetForm, and it's not working.

I tried this in "OnView" on SharePointIntegration :

```
    //ViewForm(BudgetForm);;
If(
    "DI" in SharePointIntegration.Selected.Title;
    ViewForm(DemandeForm);
    ViewForm(BudgetForm)
)
```

But it's not working. I tried the same code with ThisItem.Title in a button, after opening my app, and it works.
But I can't use ThisItem.Title in the OnView menu.

How can I use BudgetForm when title is like "BUXXX" and DemandeForm when it's "DIXXX" ?

Thanks !

Comment: When I use "ViewForm(DemandeForm)" in OnView, and select a demande... it's not working. 
I probably don't understand what I'm doing here... EDIT : I switch to Demande screen and DemandeForm, it's working. Keep looking ^^

Comment: I'm sorry to insist, but I really need to find a way to do it. Nobody knows a solution, even it's an other way to do it ?